# Recursive generator in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, yield

I am trying to create a recursive generator that generates the elements of the cartesian product of an array of arrays
E.g. [[1,2,3], [a,b,c]] : [1,a] -> [1,b] -> [1,c] -> [2,a] ..

This python code works:

```
def gen(l):
    if not l:
        yield ()
    else:
        for _ in l[0]:
            for __ in gen(l[1:]):
                yield (_,) + __
```

Why doesn't this Javascript code?

```
function* cartesianProduct(arrayOfArrays){
    if (arrayOfArrays.length === 0){
        yield []
    }else{
        for(_ of arrayOfArrays[0]){
            for(__ of cartesianProduct(arrayOfArrays.slice(1))){
                yield __.concat([_])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how yield* fits into this. I've tried every permutation, but it's still not working. Array.from() reveals it has the right number of iterations, just returning the wrong thing. I think it's more a problem with array handling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick : change `for(const _ of arrayOfArrays[0])`

```js
function* cartesianProduct(arrayOfArrays) {
  if (arrayOfArrays.length === 0) {
    yield [];
  } else {

    for (const _ of arrayOfArrays[0]) {
      for (__ of cartesianProduct(arrayOfArrays.slice(1))) {
        //updated to match your expected order
        yield [_].concat(__)
      }
    }
  }
}


let data = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
];

for (v of cartesianProduct(data)) {
  console.log(v);
}
```